# R style subset/replace in Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

In R I have a loop which runs through a data frame of people coming and leaving a site and assigns them to a parking lot until they leave when it releases the spot.

```
activity = structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1), 
          Lot = structure(c(1L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 4L), 
                          .Label = c("a", "A", "C", "d", "f", "z"), class = "factor"), 
          time = c(1, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 21), 
          dir = c(1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1),
          Here = c("no","no","no","no","no","no","no","no","no","no","no","no")), 
     class = "data.frame", 
     row.names = c(NA, -12L), .Names = c("ID", "Lot", "time", "dir","Here"))

lots = structure(c(30, 175, 170, 160, 300, 300, 35, 160, 85, 400, 200, 
                   110, 60, 130, 100, 80, 1000, 320, 330, 350, 320, 250, 250, 370, 
                   20, 40, 0, 140, 185, 200, 185, 120, 55, 105, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(34L, 2L), 
                 .Dimnames = list(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", 
                                    "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", 
                                    "u", "v", "x", "y", "z", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", 
                                    "F", "G", "H", "I"), c("Capacity", "Utilization")))

for(i in 1:nrow(activity)){
  id = activity$ID[i]
  l = activity$Lot[i]
  d = activity$dir[i]
  t = activity$time[i]
  lots[l,"Utilization"] = lots[l,"Utilization"] + d
  if(d == -1) activity$Here[activity$ID == id & activity$time <= t] = "no"
}
```

What I want to determine is, in `Rcpp` is there a way to do the R style subset and replace?  e.g., `lots[l,"Utilization"] = ...` and `activity$Here[activity$ID == id & activity$time <= t] = ...`.  I'm specifically wanting to be able to load in 3 matrices, the master record table, the matrix which manages lots and the matrix which manages current locations (in this example I know the lot already, in practice I need to determine where they are likely to park).  I have functioning code but it takes ~160 seconds to run and I'm trying to learn how to leverage `Rcpp` to make this much faster.

Comment: RCpp does have a support of `data.frame`. Check the official [examples](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppExamples/RcppExamples.pdf) and [gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/modifying-a-data-frame/).